# Velocity template that output multiple files

Tags: vuejs2, velocity, vue-component

Is there any way to write a velocity template that outputs multiple files in different paths.
I am making a velocity template that generates a Vue.js component file which has its html in a separate file.

For example..  creating Vue component with the name `Sidebar` will generate:

```
./components/Sidebar.vue
./components/templates/sidebar.template.html
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You would typically use two different templates, but you would merge them with the same context.

Documentations are usually generated using specific tools that extract objects/methods formatted comments to produce html. Such a tool would typically run on the generated component.